# How to send coupon code to customer in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I am using `Magento 1.9.1`. I already created `coupon codes`. But I don't know how to send these code to customer.?

The administrator have to send these `codes` to the customer.Then only the customer can enter the `coupon code` during checkout. So how the admin send these codes to customer? Is there any option to send the coupon code to customer in `magento`?

Please help me..
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Go to system - > Transactional Emails -> add new template or use existing one.
i have created new template.
Template Name * Welcome Email Template 
Template Subject *  Welcome, {{var customer.name}}!
Template Content * <body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}},</h1>

<hr>
Your Coupon code is  : PBOX30.

<hr>


                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0;">Welcome to {{var store.getFrontendName()}}. To log in when visiting our site just click <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">Login</a> or <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">My Account</a> at the top of every page, and then enter your e-mail address and password.</p>
                            <p style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0; padding:13px 18px; background:#f9f9f9;">
                                Use the following values when prompted to log in:<br/>
                                <strong>E-mail</strong>: {{var customer.email}}<br/>
                                <strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}<p>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;">When you log in to your account, you will be able to do the following:</p>
                            <ul style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0; padding:0;">
                                <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Proceed through checkout faster when making a purchase</li>
                                <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Check the status of orders</li>
                                <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; View past orders</li>
                                <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Make changes to your account information</li>
                                <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Change your password</li>
                                <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Store alternative addresses (for shipping to multiple family members and friends!)</li>
                            </ul>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">If you have any questions about your account or any other matter, please feel free to contact us at <a href="mailto:{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}</a> or by phone at {{config path='general/store_information/phone'}}.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

This will output Your Coupon code is : PBOX30. on new user registration. Select the template in Customer Configuration.

Comment: How can I send coupons code to the customer for ordered selected products, the coupons codes for next order?